# Key error despite key is there in the dictionary which I got from csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, dictionary

```
def duration_in_mins(datum, city):
    if city == 'Washington':
        duration = round(int(datum['Duration (ms)']) /60000, 4)
    else:
        duration = round(int(datum['tripduration']) /60 ,4)
    return duration
```

But after calling this fuction this is giving me a key error

```
def condense_data(in_file, out_file, city):
    with open(out_file, 'w') as f_out, open(in_file, 'r') as f_in:
        out_colnames = ['duration', 'month', 'hour', 'day_of_week', 'user_type']        
        trip_writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames = out_colnames)
        trip_writer.writeheader()
        trip_reader =csv.DictReader(in_file)

        for row in trip_reader:
            new_point = {}
            dur=duration_in_mins(row, city)
            month,hour, day_of_week=time_of_trip(row, city)
            type=type_of_user(row, city)
            new_point={'duration':dur, 'month':month, 'hour':hour, 'day_of_week':day_of_week, 'user_type':type}
            trip_writer.writerow(**new_point)
```

After successfully compiling the condense_data function when I'm checking it that does it is working or not,I found that it is giving me Key Error

```
KeyError: 'Duration (ms)'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code depends on data files that don't exist on our machines.  Please supply independent code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your code, though it's well writen, there simply isn't enough for me to understand your *exact* problem. However, it could be as simple as switching

```
duration = round(int(datum['Duration (ms)']) /60000, 4)
```

to:

```
duration = round(int(datum['duration']) /60000, 4)
```

Again, hard to tell without the format of your input csv, or perhaps some code is missing. This link helped me with a similar error recently:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError

This might have been entirely useless to you, but I hope not. Happy coding! And if you clarify your problem I'd be happy to look at it again.